# "Cannot access a closed file." When upload a file to Azure Blob Storage in .Net Core 3

Tags: azure, upload, azure-blob-storage, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to upload files to Azure Blob Storage, but I'm getting the following message:

"Cannot access a closed file"

This is random, if I try to load the same image twice, the first time might be loaded the second time might cause error

this is my upload function

```
private async Task<string> UploadResizedToStorage(IFormFile file, string fileName, int thumbnailWidth, IImageEncoder encoder)
    {
        try
        {
            using MemoryStream streamReader = new MemoryStream();
            await file.CopyToAsync(streamReader);
            var accountName = _config.GetValue<string>("AzureStorage:AccountName");
            var accountKey = _config.GetValue<string>("AzureStorage:AccountKey");
            var imgContainer = _config.GetValue<string>("AzureStorage:ImageContainer");
            var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
            var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(imgContainer);
            var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            streamReader.Position = 0;
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(streamReader, streamReader.Length);
            return blockBlob.SnapshotQualifiedStorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("UploadResizedToStorage "+
                               e.Message+
                             " Arquivo:"+
                             fileName);
            return "";
        }
        
    }
```

The application is hosted on Docker over Azure Application Service

The Error

```
2021-06-25T18:00:20.174050985Z: [INFO]  [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: ruralbackend.Service.StorageAzure[0]
2021-06-25T18:00:20.174102685Z: [INFO]        UploadResizedToStorage Cannot access a closed file. Arquivo:46-6.jpg
```

Comment: Can you share the actual/complete Error Stack trace?

Comment: I edited with the message that the catch returns

Comment: It might be happening because your stream is (for some reason) getting closed before/during the execution of UploadFromStreamAsync? Can you try removing `using` and disposing `streamReader` manually in a `finally` block?

Comment: looks like that's the solution. I did what you said and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be happening because your MemoryStream is (for some reason) getting closed before/during the execution of `UploadFromStreamAsync` method.

Remove the `using` keyword and dispose the `streamReader` object manually in a `finally` block at the end of execution. This will ensure that the stream is disposed only when it has completely served its purpose.